# datadog, metric, and last value

Tags: datadog

Considering I have this structure of json in datadog :

```
"parameter":
{
  "name":"mybeautifulvar",
  "value":"my_beautiful_string_value"
}
```

It's a regular extract for a value, one time a day, and I search to display the last value of this variable but I'm struggling on how to do it.

All I have been able to do is to display a count in a ***query value*** graph

index:main service:myservice @parameter.name:mybeautifulvar
count_unique:@parameter.value

How can I get the last value instead of unique count ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the feature where log values can be turned into metrics?

Refer to: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/logs_to_metrics/

Since you already have a search scope, this should be straightforward to create the metric - you'll need to choose a name.

Then you can use a [Query Value widget](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/query_value/) as you wanted and choose the `last` value aggregator to display the most recent value.